# lme4: glmer problems with offset()

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, binomial-distribution, biostatistics, offset

I have some problems with `glmer` and don't know how to fix it, so I hope somebody can help me out with this. I could not find an answer to this anywhere.

My experiment: The experimental setup has eight sites, each site has a central area in which organisms get marked. From the central area, organisms have the choice to go into three different areas which are equipped with traps. The three areas are crossed with sites. The recapture rates in these three areas are very low and the sampling effort (trap days) is very high. Due to external influences, traps got destroyed to different degrees in all the sampling areas. In addition to the marked organisms, unmarked organisms of the same species get caught, too.

The dataset looks something like this:

```r
library(lme4)
data <- structure(list(site = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "H", "H", "H"), area = c("I", "II", "III", "I", "II", "III", "I", "II", "III", "I", "II", "III", "I", "II", "III", "I", "II", "III", "I", "II", "III", "I", "II", "III"), marked = c(2, 6, 3, 5, 3, 9, 0, 8, 1, 1, 1, 18, 3, 0, 0, 1, 5, 6, 3, 0, 2, 2, 4, 5), unmarked = c(38, 78, 104, 1, 6, 10, 1, 13, 0, 13,7, 85, 7, 1, 0, 9, 4, 36, 3, 4, 3, 10, 20, 29), sampl_effort = c(9300, 9100, 8700, 9900, 9600, 8600, 9800, 9400, 10800, 11600, 11000, 13950, 10300, 9700, 9800, 10450, 10100, 10800, 9600, 9900, 9300, 11800, 11250, 9450)), .Names = c("site", "area", "marked", "unmarked", "sampl_effort"), row.names = c(NA,-24), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I wanted to fit a `glmer`. Because the amount of marked organisms may be related to the total amount of organisms, I chose to take a binomial approach, with `cbind(marked, unmarked)`. I use area with the three treatments as explanatory variable, and site as random factor. Because the sampling effort differs between the different areas, I want to include it as an offset. The code looks like this:

```r
mod.glmer1 = glmer(cbind(marked, unmarked) ~ area + (1 | site) + 
                    offset(sampl_effort), family=binomial, data=data)
```

Then, I get the error:

```r
>Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance 
    in pwrssUpdate
```

If I try the `glmer` without the offset, everything works out fine:

```r
mod.glmer2 = glmer(cbind(marked,unmarked) ~ area + (1 | site), 
                    family=binomial, data=data)
```

Out of interest, I tried a `glm` without the random factor and with offset:

```r
mod.glm1= glm(cbind(marked,unmarked) ~ area + offset(sampl_effort), 
              family=binomial, data=data)
```

and I get the following Warnings:

```r
>  Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

By looking at the fitted values

```r
round(cbind(data[,3:5], fits=fitted(mod.glm1)), 8)
```

I can see that all the fitted values are 0.

I now thought that the offset is just too large to get reasonable fitted value. As the sampling effort is arbitrary (instead of days, I could have taken sampling hours, weeks, etc.), I decided to divide the sampling effort by 1000.

By doing this, the `glm` now works:

```r
mod.glm2 = glm(cbind(marked, unmarked) ~ area + 
              offset(sampl_effort/1000), family=binomial, data=data)
```

However, for the `glmer`

```r
mod.glmer3= glmer(cbind(marked,unmarked) ~ area + (1 | site) + 
                  offset(sampl_effort/1000), family=binomial, 
                  data=data)
```

I still get

```r
> Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance
    in pwrssUpdate
```

So my questions are basically:

1. Am I allowed to divide the sampling effort by 1000? In my mind it should lead to the same results, as the relative differences in sampling effort stay the same (and sampling days are a arbitrary measurement). However, I of course tried it with e.g. dividing by 10000 and I get different results.
2. How can I include the sampling effort in the glmer? The sampling effort is just too important to keep it out, however, I also need the sites as random factor. Is the offset the right approach and if yes, why doesn't it work.

P.S.: My session information:

```r
> R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
> Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

> locale:
> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

> other attached packages:
> [1] car_2.0-19      lme4_1.0-6      Matrix_1.1-2    lattice_0.20-23

> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> [1] grid_3.0.2    MASS_7.3-29   minqa_1.2.3   nlme_3.1-111  nnet_7.3-7   
> [6] Rcpp_0.11.0   splines_3.0.2 tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: this is a little bit tricky.  Don't have time for an answer right now, but the basic issue is that the offset gets added to the model on the *linear predictor* scale.  Adding offsets to a binomial model generally makes the most sense if you are using a complementary log-log link (`family=binomial(link="cloglog")`) (google "cloglog offset" or see http://rpubs.com/bbolker/4082 for an example).  This approach **may or may not make sense for your case** -- I haven't had time to think about it.

Comment: @ Ben Bolker: Thank you so much for your fast answer. I do not know if it makes sense or not (still trying to think this through), the only thing I can say so far is that `mod.glmer4= glmer(cbind(marked,unmarked) ~ area + (1 | site) + offset(sampl_effort), family=binomial(link="cloglog"), data=data)` gives me the Error `Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, control = glmerControl(),  : 
  Downdated VtV is not positive definite`

Comment: If you did want to use an offset with a cloglog link in the standard way I believe you would need `offset(log(sample_effort))` rather than `offset(sample_effort)` -- see the link I posted.

Comment: Oh yes, my bet. However, still get the same error.

Comment: I had this error and realized that my offset term contained zeros.

Comment: It is unclear why having zeros would explain the error: could you elaborate or provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you do want to add `sampling_effort` as a offset at all.

You are estimating the logit of `marked` over `unmarked` catch probabilities - call that quantity $\eta$ -  and you think, quite reasonably, that the quantity $N=$ `marked+unmarked` will be a function of how long the traps remain undamaged, i.e. a function of `sampling_effort`.  However, it's not obvious why that relationship is relevant; your binomial model already treats $N$ as known and conditions on it.

The circumstance I can imagine where it would be relevant is when $\eta$ really depends on `sampling_effort`.  To examples would be a) if the rate of unmarked captures were constant but the rate of marked captures is increasing because of some feature of the experiment such as marked animals being expected to take a random walk from a common origin, or b) if capturing one kind of animal makes it more or less likely to capture the other type.  But even in these cases `sampling_effort` would be a regular covariate and not have its coefficient fixed at 1 as an offset would have.

Here's some possibly relevant [discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25415/using-offset-in-binomial-model-to-account-for-increased-numbers-of-patients) of this question elsewhere on the site.

Comment: @concugateprior That is an interesting thought. So basically what you say is that if sampling effort decreases, it should (under normal circumstances) decrease the likelihood to catch marked as well as unmarked individuals and thereby not affect the marked over unmarked catch probabilities? And by adding sampling_effort as covariate I would actually see if it affects the probabilities or not, right?

Comment: Exactly. Either sampling_effort affects the precision of the estimate of the marked/unmarked balance by increasing marked+unmarked, or sampling_effort affects the balance itself. If the former you don't need to add it to the model explicitly because its already conditioned on, and if the latter then it ought to be a regular covariate.