# Offset in binomial model

Tags: logistic, modeling, offset

My outcomes is binary variable.  I would like to perform logistic regression model to estimate the treatment effect of Xs. However, the follow up time was longer for outcomes=1 and shorter when outcomes=0.  The probability of the outcome can be affected by the follow up time, the longer a subject was followed up, the more chance we observe a outcome=1.  I considered including the follow up time as an offset, like poisson regression model.  Is it reasonable?  Otherwise, how can I control the difference in follow up between the two groups.

Comment: I think this question should be in StackOverflow, this post answers to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237940/offset-not-working-in-binomial-glm Cheers

Comment: Might be relevant:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25415/using-offset-in-binomial-model-to-account-for-increased-numbers-of-patients   http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155575/questionable-diagnostics-for-a-binary-logistic-model/155716#155716     http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66792/binary-models-probit-and-logit-with-a-logarithmic-offset/115106#115106

Comment: No, this post belongs here!

Comment: This sounds like you may potentially have censoring. What does 1 and 0 represent?